# In rails, updating a div with Jquery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need some guidance on how to update a div on a page with Jquery/Ajax without actually loading the page. Before I ask the question, I will provide some necessary information.

I have two models:

- **`Scoreboard` Model** (`has_many :teams`)
- **`Team` Model** (belongs_to `scoreboard`)

On **`scoreboard#show`** page, I have rendered a partial to display all **`@scoreboard.teams`**.

The partial displays all the teams in seperate divs as detailed in the following code:

```
<div class ="team-list" id="team_<%=team.id%>">
 <div class= "boxin1"><%= team.name %></div>
 <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.win %></div>
 <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.loss %></div>
 <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.tie %></div>
 <span class= "boxin3 btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_scoreboard_team_path(@scoreboard, team), remote: true %> </span>
 <span class= "boxin3 btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Del", [@scoreboard, team], remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the team?" } %>
</div>
```

Now my questions concerns the **Edit** button which on click, calls for an ajax request which, brings up a **form** to edit a team, and then the form, on submission, calls for the update method in the Teams Controller. For further clarification, here is the relevant code:

**Team Controller methods for edit and update:**

```
  def edit
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @team = @scoreboard.teams.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to scoreboard_url(@team.scoreboard_id)}
         format.js
     end
   end

    def update
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @team = @scoreboard.teams.find(params[:id])
    if @team.update_attributes(team_params)
     respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to scoreboard_url(@team.scoreboard_id)}
         format.js
     end
    else
     render 'edit'
    end
   end
```

Here is the code for the edit.js.erb and update.js.erb files and description to clarify what is happening in them:

**edit.js.erb**

```
$("#team_<%=@team.id%>").hide();
$("#team_<%=@team.id%>").after("<%= j render 'teamedit'%>");
```

So upon clicking the edit_path link button, the div for team being edited is hidden, and a **teamedit** form is rendered right after it.

**update.js.erb**

```
$("#edit_team_<%=@team.id%>").hide();
$("#team_<%=@team.id%>").load("scoreboards/show.html.erb"); #help needed here
$("#team_<%=@team.id%>").show();
```

Now when the update controller method is called after form submission, the form is hidden with jquery, and I want to **reload the team div** that I hid earlier, and then show it with its updated values.

I felt like the .load() jquery method would be relevant in refreshing that div with the new edited values however it is not working. In conclusion, **edit.js.erb** works fine but **update.js.erb** does not work due to the 2nd line in the code. The div is not being refreshed with updated values. Could anyone offer some guidance on a different method or let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

Another item of relevance. Team_Params method In Teams controllers:

```
 private

   def team_params
     params.require(:team).permit(:name, :win, :loss, :tie)
   end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost done everything.

The only remaining part is to put team information into a partial, named e.g. `_team.html.erb`:

```
<div class ="team-list" id="team_<%=team.id%>">
  <div class= "boxin1"><%= team.name %></div>
  <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.win %></div>
  <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.loss %></div>
  <div class= "boxin2"><%= team.tie %></div>
  <span class= "boxin3 btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_scoreboard_team_path(@scoreboard, team), remote: true %> </span>
  <span class= "boxin3 btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Del", [@scoreboard, team], remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the team?" } %>
</div>
```

and then `update.js.erb`:

```
$("#edit_team_<%=@team.id%>").hide();
$("#team_<%=@team.id%>").load("<%= j render partial: 'team', locals: {team: @team} %>");
$("#team_<%=@team.id%>").show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did as you instructed and the form is hidden and the div re-shows. However, when the div shows, it's still with the old values for @team and not the ones that were input into the edit form. Anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is your `team_params` method. Can you show it too?

Comment: Private is not problem here. It's somewhere else. Hard to say. If you can share your project it would be fast to identify what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**ERB**

Furthering `dimakura`'s answer, it seems you need some help with the understanding of the [`js erb` infrastructure](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example):

> Notice the format.js in the respond_to block; that allows the
>   controller to respond to your Ajax request. You then have a
>   corresponding app/views/users/create.js.erb view file that generates
>   the actual JavaScript code that will be sent and executed on the
>   client side.

Contrary to the standard asset-pipeline, controller-generated `JS.erb` allows you to invoke `ERB` functionality with any instance variables set in your controller.

As such, your question of how to "load" another ERB view into your JS can be handled using the *render* method in ERB:

```
#app/views/teams/update.js.erv
$("#team_<%=j @team.id %>").replacewith('<%=j render("scoreboards/show") %>');
```

The target view is up to you. Seems `dimakura` used a partial, it's up to you which one you go with.

--

**Process**

In regards your comments about processing the new data, you have to understand that in `js.erb`, you'll have access to the same data that you'd have in any other controller action.

This means that if you're not receiving the most up-to-date data, it's a systemic problem.

I would do the following:

```
#app/controllers/teams_controller.rb
class Teamscontroller < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_vars

   def edit
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @scoreboard }
        format.js
     end
   end

   def update
     respond_to do |format|
       if @team.update team_params
         format.html { redirect_to @scoreboard }
         format.js
       else
         format.html { render :edit }
     end
   end

   private

   def set_vars
      @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find params[:scoreboard_id]
      @team = @scoreboard.teams.find params[:id]
   end

   def team_params
     params.require(:team).permit(:name, :win, :loss, :tie)
   end
end
```

If this doesn't work, it generally means you've got a problem with your update process (IE `update` won't be working properly).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your update method is working? I would check that first. You need to include scoreboard_id in your team_params method.